# Running Spark jobs from Spring RESTful services

Tags: java, spring, scala, rest, apache-spark

I want to run Spark jobs by REST APIs, and I want to use Scala for Spark. I have a mixed Java & Scala project with Spring framework. I can call a Scala method that creates a SparkContext and does some job by a REST API. The problem occurs when setting the master remote, not local.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("App").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

is fine, but

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("App").setMaster(" spark://10.122.221.164:7077")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

causes `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

The solutions I could find so far are creating a fat-jar and do `conf.setJars(...)`, or using `spark-submit` script via something like `ProcessBuilder`.

In my current setting I have only a Spring project including the Spark Scala codes that is packed into a `war` file to run under Tomcat etc., so I don't have a fat-jar. I don't want to have a Spring project and several separate Scala applications each packed as a fat-jar. How can I come up with a simple but reasonable architecture?

Comment: Why don't you use Maven and add dependencies in pom.xml? I have used Spring and Spark together. Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: @Dip I already use Maven. I can use `mvn package` in order to build a fat jar, but I don't understand why I have to separate these Spring project and Spark driver app.

Answer (score 1):

Which class gives a ClassNotFoundException ? It should be clear from that, that you Spark application has a dependency on that class and needs to be packaged along with the Spark application.

It works locally because it has all the jars available, but for remote, the dependency jars needs to be transfered to the driver/executors.

If you run the spark-submit you can see the dependency jars specified using --jars are transfered.

You can create a uber jar or specify the dependency jars using using SparkConf.setJars.

Maven Shade plugin can be used to create a uber jar, and specify just the jars that needs to be bundled.

Also why don't you use [SparkLauncher](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/package-summary.html) to launch Spark applications.

Comment: So is there no way to call the Spark application with SparkContext as a method in the Spring web application unless it is not configured locally? Even if I use SparkLauncher, I need to create a fat jar for Spark application, so I need to have two distinct projects. I use Maven Assembly plugin, I think it is similar to Maven Shade.

Comment: The only way to submit spark application is through spark-submit or SparkLauncher. You will initialize SparkConf/SparkContext as part of you spark application and not to launch spark application. Yes you need to create fat jar or specify dependency jars.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
    public  SparkSession sparkSession() {

        SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
                .master(getWorkerThreadCount())
                .appName("SparkApp"+System.currentTimeMillis())
                /*  Spark UI Config */
                .config("spark.ui.enabled", true)
                .config("spark.ui.killEnabled", true)
                .config("spark.ui.retainedJobs", 100)
                .config("spark.ui.retainedStages", 100)
                .config("spark.ui.retainedTasks", 1000)
                .config("spark.cleaner.periodicGC.interval","3min")
                /* Spark performance configs */
//                .config("spark.driver.memory", driveryMemory)
//                .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",shuffleParitions)
                .config("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled",true)
                .config("spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.blocking","false")

//                .config("spark.cleaner.periodicGC.interval", "10min")
                .getOrCreate()
                .newSession();

        sparkSession.sparkContext().setLogLevel("DEBUG");
        LOGGER.info("Started Spark App ::: UI at : " + sparkSession.sparkContext().uiWebUrl().get());

        return sparkSession;
    }
```

We are currently using this code to run Spark inside Spring boot

```
 Dataset<Row> dremioDataSet = sparkSession.read()
                .format("jdbc")
                .option("url", dbConfigurations.getUrl().toString())
                .option("driver", dbConfigurations.getDriver().toString())
                .option("user", dbConfigurations.getUsername().toString())
                .option("password", dbConfigurations.getPassword().toString())
                .option("dbtable", "(" + finalQuery + ") ")
                .load();
```

Comment: But are facing a lot of latency issues for concurrent requests. Anyone has any idea for solving this.